# what is the working directory for jar laucher in apache storm topology jar

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am a novice in Apache Storm. I have created a storm project in java and it successfully creates. My Application had a java process which needs absolute path of the application working directory or class path of the topology jar. please answer my following question:

1. What is the path of the class files of a topology jar which we
   upload using storm jar command ?
2. I am java process which need some JVM parameters, i had tried
   setting them in storm.yaml file. Is it right way to do or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uploaded jars go into `{storm.local.dir}/nimbus/inbox` (or something similar -- can't remember exactly). `storm.local.dir` is configured in `storm.yaml`.

Using `worker.childopts` in `storm.yaml` to set worker JVM options is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

After trying  different type of use cases and options available in internet, i found solution to my problem.

Using topology.classpath in topology Config to set the classpath of the jars i want to read its working.

Comment: I see. You actually wanted to use external jars... You did not mentioned that in you original question... The most common way to include additional jars, is to build a fat-jar that contains the topology as well as all external dependencies. Pay attention, that nested jars are not supported by Storm (ie, you need to include the content of an external jar in your topology jar, but not the external jar itself). As an alternative to `topology.classpath` you can copy additional jars into `$STORM/lib` on each supervisor node.